# Is this a property of the sine function?

Tags: real-analysis, random-variables, epsilon-delta, ergodic-theory

Because of the equidistribution property of $\{n\mod{2\pi}\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ in $[0,2\pi]$, my intuition tells me that the following statement about the sine function must be true.

We can find an **absolute constant** $C>0$ such that for all $\epsilon>0$ and all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ there exists a $n' \in \mathbb{Z}$  with $|n'-n|<C\epsilon^{-1}$ and $|\sin{n'}|<\epsilon$.

First, is this true? And if it is/isn't, how can it be shown? And is this statement equivalent to (or follows from) a well-known theorem?

Comment: For $\epsilon=C$ there are no $n'\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $|n'-n|<1$?

Comment: Dromasty, the question says $|n-n’|<C\epsilon^{-1}$, so a small $\epsilon$ leads to a large $\epsilon^{-1}$ and therefore a large $C \epsilon^{-1}$.

Comment: Surely you want to show something else. Perhaps the following interesting property (which follows from your first sentence): given $n\in\mathbb Z$ and $\varepsilon>0$, there exists an integer $m>n$ such that $\lvert\sin m-\sin n\rvert <\varepsilon$.

Comment: @dromastyx The inequality $|n'-n|<1$ can be satisfied by taking $n'=n$. Of course, that gives us no control over $\sin n'$, but we still get the desired $|\sin n'|<\epsilon$ if $\epsilon>1$. And your choice of $\epsilon$, namely $C$, will be $>1$ if we just take a nice big value for $C$.  In other words, we never need to worry about the case where $\epsilon>1$ because $n'=n$ will always work in that case. So the question is really only about (moderately) small values of $\epsilon$, namely $\epsilon\leq1$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I see, completely missed that $n=n'$ was a possibility.

Comment: My hunch is that we can use the irrationality measure of $\pi$ to our advantage. This is because $|n'/k-\pi|<\delta/k$ implies $|\sin{n'}|<\epsilon$. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is equivalent to $\{n \mod 2\pi\}$ equidistributing quickly.

Writing $n' = n+k$, we want some $|k| \le C\epsilon^{-1}$ with $\epsilon > \sin(n') = \sin(n+k) = \sin(2\pi(\frac{n+k}{2\pi}))$ $= \sin\left(2\pi(\lfloor \frac{n}{2\pi}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{k}{2\pi}\rfloor+\{\frac{n}{2\pi}\}+\{\frac{k}{2\pi}\})\right)$ $= \sin(2\pi \{\frac{n}{2\pi}\}+2\pi\{\frac{k}{2\pi}\})$. Since $n$ is arbitrary, $\{\frac{n}{2\pi}\}$ can basically be anything, so you need/want $\{\frac{k}{2\pi}\}$ to create an $\asymp\epsilon$-net in $[0,1]$ (note $\sin(x) \asymp x$ for small $x$) for $|k| \lesssim \epsilon^{-1}$.

If you didn't understand that and want full rigor, here ya go.

> Potential Claim: There exists an absolute $C > 0$ such that for any $\epsilon > 0$, the set $\{\{\frac{k}{2\pi}\} : |k| \le C\epsilon^{-1}\}$ intersects each interval of size $\frac{\epsilon}{10}$ in $[0,1]$.

.

> If Potential Claim is true, then answer to your question is "yes".
>
> Proof: Take $C$ as in potential claim and $\epsilon > 0$. Take any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Take $|k| \le C\epsilon^{-1}$ such that $\{\frac{k}{2\pi}\} \in [1-\{\frac{n}{2\pi}\}-\frac{\epsilon}{20},1-\{\frac{n}{2\pi}\}+\frac{\epsilon}{20}]$ (if $1-\{\frac{n}{2\pi}\} < \frac{\epsilon}{20}$, just use $[1-\{\frac{n}{2\pi}\},1-\{\frac{n}{2\pi}\}+\frac{\epsilon}{10}]$ and analogously if $1-\{\frac{n}{2\pi}\} > 1-\frac{\epsilon}{20}$). Let $n' = n+k$. Then $|\sin(n')| = |\sin\left(2\pi(\{\frac{n}{2\pi}\}+\{\frac{k}{2\pi}\})\right)| < \epsilon$ since $|2\pi(\{\frac{n}{2\pi}\}+\{\frac{k}{2\pi}\})| \le 2\pi\frac{\epsilon}{20} \le \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

.

> If Potential Claim is false, then the answer to your question is "no".
>
> Proof: I'll leave this to you. I basically already explained it at the top of my answer.

.

So, is the Potential Claim true? Well, this is related to the [discrepancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence#Discrepancy) of an [irrational rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_rotation) on the torus (note that we are adding $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ mod $1$ each time we increase $k$ by $1$). And this is related to the continued fraction expansion of the rotation, in this case $\frac{1}{2\pi}$. I just googled and found [this](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s10474-017-0702-x.pdf) for one such reference (containing many other references).